# VB.Net Process Start Info With Arguments

Tags: vb.net

Hello Can Anyone please help me i have a code here but it wont work when i use the argumenets
maybe someone can help me out

```
  Dim procStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
            Dim InstallVirtualBoxSetup As New Process
            Dim Output As String = InstallVirtualBoxSetup.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

            'Run As Admin
            With procStartInfo
                .UseShellExecute = True
                .FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Components\Virtualbox.msi" & """ -quiet -norestart -l vlog.txt VBOX_INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT=0 VBOX_INSTALLQUICKLAUNCHSHORTCUT=0 VBOX_START=0 VBOX_REGISTERFILEEXTENSIONS=1"
                .Arguments = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Components\Virtualbox.msi" & """ -quiet -norestart -l vlog.txt VBOX_INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT=0 VBOX_INSTALLQUICKLAUNCHSHORTCUT=0 VBOX_START=0 VBOX_REGISTERFILEEXTENSIONS=1"
                .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                .Verb = "runas" 'add this to prompt for elevation
            End With


            InstallVirtualBoxSetup = Process.Start(procStartInfo)

            Output = InstallVirtualBoxSetup.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
            InstallVirtualBoxSetup.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: It looks like there are arguments in the .FileName and the filename in the .Arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Arguments`, you should supply a list of the arguments only, without the file being executed.

The `FileName` should just be the path to the executed\opened file.

Here's the code that's been changed to reflect this:

```
With procStartInfo
    .UseShellExecute = True
    .FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Components\Virtualbox.msi"
    .Arguments = "-quiet -norestart -l vlog.txt VBOX_INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT=0 VBOX_INSTALLQUICKLAUNCHSHORTCUT=0 VBOX_START=0 VBOX_REGISTERFILEEXTENSIONS=1"
    .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    .Verb = "runas" 'add this to prompt for elevation
End With
```

Comment: it showed no application is associated with the specified file for this operation